# Trying to convert lodash code to es6 methods; it's throwing error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

so below commented out code is working in lodash just wanted to convert into es6 to make it simpler and clearer code its throwing error some is undefined. any help here ?

main.js

```
        const rejectMessagerrors = [45,67,87];
        const drug = [{
            "isBrand": true,
            "drugName": "Lipitor",
            "specialtyPrice": {}
          },
          {
            "isBrand": false,
            "drugName": "Atorvastatin Calcium",
            "drugStrength": "80mg",
            "drugForm": "Tablet",
            "mailPrice": {
              "totalQuantity": 90,
              "rejectMessage": [{
                "settlementCode": "45",
                "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
              }]
            },
            "retailPrice": {
              "totalQuantity": 30,
              "rejectMessage": [{
                "settlementCode": "99",
                "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
              }]
            },
            "specialtyPrice": {}
          }
        ];

            function priceFilterHandler(drug) {
                // const pricePath = ['mailPrice.rejectMessage', 'retailPrice.rejectMessage'];
  //
  // _.forEach(pricePath, function (path) {
  //   const rejectMsg = _.get(drug, path);
  //   const hasCode = rejectMsg && rejectMsg.find(i => !!~rejectMessagerrors.indexOf(+i.settlementCode));
  //   hasCode && delete drug[path.split('.').shift()];
  // });
  const retailHasCode = findErrCode(item.retailPrice.rejectMessage);
  const mailHasCode = findErrCode(item.mailPrice.rejectMessage);

  if (retailHasCode) {
    delete item.retailPrice;
  }

  if (mailHasCode) {
    delete item.mailPrice;
  }

  return item;
            }

   const filteredPrices = _.map(drug, priceFilterHandler);
```

findErr method

```
let findErrCode = data => {
  data.some(i => rejectMessagerrors.includes(+i.settlementCode));
}
```

expected output

Because `mailPrice` in contains settlementCode 45 that price should be omitted it matches the `rejectMessagerrors` list element

```
[{
                "isBrand": true,
                "drugName": "Lipitor",
                "specialtyPrice": {}
              },
              {
                "isBrand": false,
                "drugName": "Atorvastatin Calcium",
                "drugStrength": "80mg",
                "drugForm": "Tablet",
                "retailPrice": {
                  "totalQuantity": 30,
                  "rejectMessage": [{
                    "settlementCode": "99",
                    "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
                  }]
                },
                "specialtyPrice": {}
              }
            ];
```

Comment: you're not returning anything from `findError` function

Comment: @CodeManiac that doesn't solve the problem it still says some undefined

Comment: can you post desired output ? will try to post as an working snippet to cover all problems

Comment: Note that you are talking about stuff that was added in es*5*, not es6...

Comment: @CodeManiac i added expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some problems you had in your code

- No return value from `findError` function
- some element don't have `mailPrice or retailPrice` where you try to access `item.mailPrice.rejetcMessage`

```js
const rejectMessagerrors = [45, 67, 87];
const drug = [{"isBrand": true,"drugName": "Lipitor","specialtyPrice": {}},{"isBrand": false,"drugName": "Atorvastatin Calcium","drugStrength": "80mg","drugForm": "Tablet","mailPrice": {"totalQuantity": 90,"rejectMessage": [{"settlementCode": "45","settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"}]},"retailPrice": {"totalQuantity": 30,"rejectMessage": [{"settlementCode": "99","settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"}]},"specialtyPrice": {}}];

let findErrCode = data => data && data.some(i => rejectMessagerrors.includes(+i.settlementCode));

let op = drug.map(item=> {
const retailHasCode = findErrCode(item.retailPrice && item.retailPrice.rejectMessage);
  const mailHasCode = findErrCode(item.mailPrice && item.mailPrice.rejectMessage);

  if (retailHasCode) {
    delete item.retailPrice;
  }

  if (mailHasCode) {
    delete item.mailPrice;
  }

  return item;
})

console.log(op)
```

Comment: sometime object does not return `rejectMessage` part of the drug should i add another if condition before calling `findErr` method

Comment: @hussain notice `data && data.some` in `findError` if your `item.mailPrice.rejectMessage` is falsy value it will not `data.some` part

Comment: sorry i got it i think

Comment: so you think this would be best approach for desired result or we can make it better

Comment: @hussain one thing can be improved is use `object` or `Set` instead of array for `rejectMessagerrors`, so need not to loop to check for value

Comment: what would happen if rejectMessage come as an empty array like `rejectMessage:[]` does findErr still evaluate the value or it will throw error